# How to measure Memory Increase

Tags: performance, memory, memory-leaks

We need to measure memory increase for an application on Windows. We currently use Resource Monitor by checking the application entry and recording the Working Set and Committed and by constantly monitoring hour by hour, memory increase is reported. I appreciate if there is other method to get the values automatically and exported in txt or csv files.

All thoughts are great and appreciated.

Comment: it'd be good to know what programming language the application is written in

Comment: The application is written in two different languages C++ and Java. It is a combination of these two languages.

Comment: With the Java portion, you could use jvisualvm or JProfile. Is it a spring boot application?